# Get noise through the microphone

Tags: android

In my Android application I need to automatically turn on the microphone, record the noise and calculate the Db level. How can I do this?

So far I have tried the following code:

```
import android.media.MediaRecorder;

public class SoundMeter {

    static final private double EMA_FILTER = 0.6;

    private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;
    private double mEMA = 0.0;

    public void start() {
        if (mRecorder == null) {
            mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            mRecorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null"); 
            mRecorder.prepare();
            mRecorder.start();
            mEMA = 0.0;
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (mRecorder != null) {
            mRecorder.stop();       
            mRecorder.release();
            mRecorder = null;
        }
    }

    public double getAmplitude() {
        if (mRecorder != null)
            return  (mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude()/2700.0);
        else
            return 0;
    }

    public double getAmplitudeEMA() {
        double amp = getAmplitude();
        mEMA = EMA_FILTER * amp + (1.0 - EMA_FILTER) * mEMA;
        return mEMA;
    }

}
```

But I couldn't do what I need to do. I'm new to Android development so if you have any idea please let me know.

Comment: Try putting all these methods in your main activity and then try calling start or getAmplitude etc from the onCreate method (which is the entry point of your android app)

Comment: I could store the sound to the SD card through below code. But I want to automatically on the microphone, get noise and calculate the Db value.

http://www.androiddevblog.net/android/android-audio-recording-part-1

any ideas ..

Comment: I get it, okay, so at what interval would you typically need to calculate the Db value? Do you need to do it once for the whole recording or say once every second?

Comment: I need to do it once for the whole recording. Here I want to record the noise automatically (without pressing button in the GUI ) And then calculate the Db value

Comment: Actually I need to measure the Db level of airbag deployment through the microphone of the android phone.To do that practically we cant have a GUT to press button. The code of the above link have a GUI to press button to start recording and another button to stop the recording. I need to do those two things automatically.